# How to make a list of lists into single list F#

Tags: f#

I have a list of lists

```
LL = [[1;2;3];[4;5;6];[7;8;9]]
```

And I would like it to look like this

```
LSimple= [1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9]
```

That's as simple as I can ask it, but maybe rewording helps. How can I parse this lists of lists and create a simple list from it?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
List.concat LL
```

Will do what you want. The X.concat family of functions concatenate any sequence of the collection X to a single X where X may be a `List`, `Array`, `Seq` or even a `String` with a given separator.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the implementation of List.concat it could be highly inefficient. if it is implemented with the naive approach it will use the naive way for a single appending.
for the simple case: assume that we got two list xs ys we wish to append together.

then the implementation would be

```
let rec append =
    function
    | [], ys -> ys
    | xs, [] -> xs
    | x::xs, y::ys -> append(x :: append (xs,[y]), ys)
```

This is the most inefficient implementation there is, another implementation will simple replace the last case return with

```
x::append(xs,y::ys)
```

Both has O(n) running time. but the last will have a smaller konstant k (k*n).

The most effecient way with 2*k*n run time are given below. where n is the number of elements, and k is the kost of concatenating a single element to a list.

```
let collapse lst =
   let rec help acc =
      function
      | [] -> // conversion point
         List.rev acc
      | (x :: []) :: xss -> // singleton case
         help (x :: acc) xss
      | (x :: xs) :: xss -> // general case
         help (x :: acc) (xs :: xss)
   help [] lst // return
```

In general, don't trust libraries when it comes to efficiency, and be aware that those who make them are just humans as you, so there can be a lot of bugs.